# Angular js http.get request not hitting my url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

as i am working on angular js for using the rest-full web services in my website,
but my problem is i am getting controll into error field instead of success and i stucked into it since past three days any help will be appreciated more, and this is my anguls js code.
`

```
    function customersController1($scope, $http) {

         $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:9090/quote',
            dataType: 'text/json',
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"

            }

        }).success(function(data){
            $scope.data = data;
            alert(data);
        }).error(function(error){
            $scope.error = error;
            alert('error');

        }); 
    }

</script>
`enter code here`<div ng-controller="customersController1">
    <!-- div>{{ quotes }}</div-->
    <ul>
        cc <li ng-repeat="quotes"> cc{{ quotes }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

thanks in advance friends.

Comment: Please check in firbug net tab.what error code displayed there?

Comment: no errors are there but instead in response tab, respose is null(empty)

Comment: That's mean there is some problem in response that you are sending from this webservice.As it is hitting the respective url without any error code.May be here you defined content type as json and this url is returning other content type.Also you can use ajax .complete callback function.Ajax call will always come in this callback function and sometimes because of content types it happens that it will not go in success & error call back but it always goes in complete call back.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure the url is working by accessing it in browser and then ensure sure you are using ng-app in your html .

Next  -

$http's config object doesn't have ant property 'dataType'. you can remove and try your example.

```
$http(
    {
        method : 'GET',
        url : 'http://localhost:9090/quote',
    }
).success( function(data, status, headers, config) 
{

})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config)
{
});
```

or else you can even use $http's get method to for http get calls.

```
var config = {};
$http.get('http://localhost:9090/quote', config)
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {});
```

To know more, read - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get

A note - content-type header is usually sent in http request header while making an POST/PUT call to specify the content type sent from client to server. In your case, you may not need the header.

To know more read - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: Thanks for suggestion Rabi, here is some details. and this is url localhost:9090/quote response`[{"id":1,"fullName":"vinod","address":"Bang-2000","line1":"gumpa","city":"Bidar","state":"Karnataka","zip":"12345"}]`

Comment: did you check the response code while calling from Angular? what response code are you getting ?